# Why do I occasionally get "Undefined Offset 8?"

Tags: php

I have a bit of code that occasionally returns and "Undefined Offset 8."

I searched and I can't find the "Undefined Offset" definitions, making it more mysterious.

Here's the code:

```
while($lowest_plays !== $plays[$x]){
    $x = rand(0,count($plays));
}
```

The offset occurs on the while loop, which seems to be where this particular offset usually occurs. The $lowest_plays and $plays variables are always normal and I don't see any pattern for when the "Undefined Offset" occurs.

The variable `$x` is a random number between `0` and `$plays-1`.

Here are the values for one of the "Undefined Offset 8" notices:

```
Plays: Array ( [0] => 147 [1] => 147 [2] => 146 [3] => 147 [4] => 147 [5] => 146 [6] => 147 [7] => 146 ) 
Lowest Plays: 146
Random variable ($): 1
```

Comment: The last array index is `count($array) - 1`. You are randomizing between 0 and the array length. But last index < length.

Comment: Please reread the manual page for [`rand()`](http://sg3.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php#refsect1-function.rand-returnvalues).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays are zero-indexed, so the array items are $plays[0].. upto $plays[7]. `count` is 8 - the total number of elements. So you need

```
$x = rand(0,count($plays) - 1);
```

otherwise at some stage you are attempting to read `$plays[8]` which doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, I see. I have `$x = rand(0,count($plays)-1);` before the while loop, but it wasn't changed afterwards. Good eye. First I saw this, and was like, "I already did that," then I saw what was going on. Thanks! Very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Quoted from your question:

> The variable $x is a random number between 0 and $plays - 1.

If that were true, you wouldn't have a problem, but looking at the return value of [`rand(min, max)`](http://sg3.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php#refsect1-function.rand-returnvalues), it states (highlights my own):

> A pseudo random value between min (or 0) and max (or [getrandmax()](http://sg3.php.net/manual/en/function.getrandmax.php), **inclusive**).

Therefore, the correct statement should be:

```
$x = rand(0,count($plays) - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

In `$plays`, you do not have any entry with index 8. The `rand` function includes both `$min` and `$max` so you need

```
$x = rand(0, count($plays)-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are generating a random number between 0 and `count($plays)` to use as an index into $plays[]. The **size** of plays is 8 elements, but the indexes run from 0 to 7.

You should be calculating your randim number like this:

```
while($lowest_plays !== $plays[$x]){
  $x = rand(0,count($plays)-1);    // random from 0 to 7
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 8 elements in the array so

```
rand(0, count($plays))
```

will give you a random integer from 0 to 8;

if it happen to give you the 8, and you try to access $plays[8], that's where the error is about. The correct way:

```
rand(0, count($plays)-1)
```